# very noob question about ruby inheritance, ruby object inside FXRuby

Tags: ruby, inheritance, fxruby

first sorry for my poor english...I've a doubt..I'm reading the FXRuby for the pragmatic programmer..and I saw this code

```
require 'fox16'
include Fox
class HelloWindow < FXMainWindow
    def initialize(app)
        super(app, "Hello, World!" , :width => 200, :height => 100)
    end   

    def  create
      super
      show(PLACEMENT_SCREEN)
    end

end


app = FXApp.new
HelloWindow.new(app)
app.create
app.run
```

It's a very basic example...actually It's he first example..but I'm so noob than I don't understand it:

app is a FXAPP object..
now I create a HelloWindow object and pass my FXApp object named "app"

so far so good

but now...in the book write app.create
I'm calling the "create" method inside FXApp class...or not?..

why when I call app.create..ruby call the create method inside HelloWindow?..app is a very different object than HelloWindow class and I could can call an anscestor method (like when I use super) but not at the inverse way...

why they don't call it something like this

```
helloobject=HelloWindow.new(app)
helloobject.create
```

this way I calling the create method inside HelloWindows class..and it is descendent from FXMainWindows

I hope than you can understand (sorry for my bad english) and can help me

thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about FXRuby, but I answer your questions about the Ruby side of things.

When Ruby executes `app.create`, it will call the `create` method inside the FXApp class because `app`'s type is FXApp (assuming that there is no `create` method defined for the [singleton class of app](http://www.contextualdevelopment.com/articles/2008/ruby-singleton)).

When you call `app.create`, there is probably some code in the FXApp class to calls `create` on all of the windows in the app, so that's how your window's `create` function gets called.  If you want to really find out how your window's `create` function is being called, try adding `raise "hello"` to it and see if you get a backtrace of the exception.

I don't really know the answer to your last question because it has to do with the design of the FXRuby library.  But conceptually it seems like calling `app.create` and `window.create` are very different things.  If you want to run the app, you should create it first.  Simply creating one window isn't good enough.